# UK foreign aid to India

Tags: united-kingdom, india, foreign-aid

In 2012 there were quite a few headlines in the UK press around the commitment to end financial aid to India by 2015 e.g. [this article from the BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-20265583).

Did this happen?

My own Googling can only show figures up to 2015, nothing about 2016/2017 figures or statements of intent.

Comment: Interesting, India is in dire need of education and skills, not money. The place is challenged for resources and only knowing people can work together to fix that. We can help there. Having travelled to india, workes at end of colonial period still recall being hit with sticks to build railways by brits, and the bans on indian processing of cotton and general plunder of the people. don't crowd fund, crowd source. get your crowds to directly finance and aid each other. crowd funding is a failure in politics.

Comment: @com.prehens.ible money buys education, your opening sentence is bizarre to me.

Comment: Most foreign aid is spent on infrastructure, and the amount of grafting and lost money is incredible. The net balance of payments of the last century probably tips heavily in the UK's direction.

Comment: Still don't understand you. "Infrastructure" or "money" could mean schools and teachers. I think you just mean to say you think it's spent on the wrong projects.

Comment: 50 percent of indians have a different agreement. When Aid comes in it's already hawked over by indian offices who do huge infrastructure projects with billion of pounds awarded to foreigners. Britain doesn't have anything to say about the spending. If britain bought INDIA stuff that a british government select comittee thought very useful for INDIA... theyd have  Dustbins and recycling factories, Water purity systems and Plumbing, because, good luck drinking Indian water off the mountain fountains. water and cement and industrial destruction monitoring agencies, playgrounds, solar.

Answer (score 2):

The data comes from the DfID, who publish [Statistics on International Development](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/department-for-international-development/about/statistics) annually. The last published data was in Nov. 2016, and included data about 2015 (when £186m was spent on bilateral aid to India.)

At the time of writing, the 2017 report, that would contain the data for 2016, hasn't been released. It would normally be released at the end of November, or the start of December.

The provisional report on 2016 spending doesn't break down spending per country, although I note that total spending on Asia remained the same proportion as in 2015, and as the total budget had increased this means a real-terms increase in spending.

About 80% of the aid budget is spent by DfID and about 2/3 of that is bilateral aid, from one government to another. The remaining 1/3 goes through multinational agencies such as Unicef.

The commitment, as I understand it, only applied to direct bilateral aid, and not all spending in India, such as technical support, which could be increased.